# Mysql replace query with regular expressions for forum quote tags

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm looking for a way run a query which only replaces phrases within "[QUOTE=XXX]" tags.

*For example:*

> [QUOTE=**User Peter**]Hello. This text should not be affected.[/QUOTE]
>
> [QUOTE=**Moderator John**]Hello. This text should not be
>   affected.[/QUOTE]

I would like to remove the Phrase **User** and **Moderator** using a mysql query.

However, the following should also not be affected:

> [QUOTE=Tom]Hello Moderator John.[/QUOTE]

This is my current query:

```
UPDATE post SET pagetext = REPLACE(REPLACE(pagetext, 'User', '') , 'Moderator', '') WHERE pagetext REGEXP '\\[QUOTE=*\\]';
```

I need some help with the regex part.

I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Try see if this works;

`UPDATE post SET pagetext = REPLACE(REPLACE(pagetext, 'User', '') , 'Moderator', '') WHERE pagetext LIKE '%[QUOTE=%';`